# two IF statements vs. one AND statement

Tags: java, performance

Within java I wonder which of these is more efficient:

```
if(something)
   {
      if(something)
    }
```

or

```
if((something) &&(something))
```

I was wondering what the merits are for both in terms of performance. Which solutions lend themselves better to different data objects.

Comment: the first way is typically seen in code written by people who don't know/understand that the `&&` operator short-circuits. I have seen 15+ cascading `if` blocks in legacy code, and promptly replaced them all with the second way. (Aside: The VB.NET `And` is one such example where it doesn't short-circuit, but `AndAlso` does)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Performance will be identical. The first statement will be evaluated and only if it is true will the second one be evaluated.

This is merely a question of readability. Unless there is something that needs to be done if the first statement is true, regardless of the second, I'd go with both in the same line as it is clearer that both statements need to be true for something to happen. You also don't have to indent unnecessarily.

Comment: I think two 'if' statements is better for readability if some conditions are checked using multiple boolean operations and there are multiple conditions.

For example, to check if "num is a power of 2" and "size is positive", I think it would be more difficult to read if one writes (python) "if num > 0 and num & (num-1) == 0 and size == 0: ..."

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `&&` short-circuits. This means that if the first condition in `a && b` evaluates to `false`, the second condition isn't even evaluated.

Therefore, the two almost certainly result in identical code, and there's no performance difference.

Of the two forms, you should use whichever results in clearer code.

Answer (score 2):

In general they are the same. If the first one is evaluated false, the second one will not be evaluated. In case you want something to happen if the first one is false, you should use the separate if-statement. Otherwise, if you only want to be sure both are true and do nothing if one of them return false, you can use the second option.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `&&` operator in Java is a short circuit operator. That means that if the expression on the left side of the `&&` is `false`, Java won't bother to evaluate the expresion on the right side, because the result of is going to be `false`, no matter what the right hand side expression evaluates to.

So, effectively, the performance of these two constructions will be the same.

Note that Java also has an `&` operator. That one does not short circuit: it will always evaluate the expressions on both sides of the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but, by intuition, I think that once compiled into bytecode there is no difference...